# how to capture the "Menu Item 1" text in the dropdown button and assign to textbox

Tags: button, drop-down-menu

I am using a code snippet from codeproject of dropdown button.

```
<    m:SplitButton Content="TWB" Name="btnSearch"
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                          Style="{StaticResource aeroNormalColorSplitButtonStyle}"
                          Click="btnSearch_Click" 
                          Width="60" Height="30"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
                          Mode="{Binding ElementName=modeSelector, Path=SelectedItem}"
                          Placement="{Binding ElementName=placementSelector, Path=SelectedItem}" MouseLeftButtonDown="btnSearch_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                MenuItem Header="TWB"/&gt;
                                MenuItem Header="PWB"&gt;
                                /MenuItem&gt;
                          </m:SplitButton>
```

so, beside this splitdown button, I have a textbox(which is basically a search box). So, as the above code snippet shows the 2 menu items as "TWB" and "PWB", I have to fill the textbox when TWB is selected from the dropdown button and also the same text should be displayed on the button too (TWB).

if i click PWB from the dropdownbutton, I should get the   "PWB" name on the button and the same PWB name should be displayed in the textbox too.

Please help me.

Thank You,
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

I tried by adding ListBox to the SplitButton, Now I am able to see the text in the textbox.

Modified the above Xaml code to

```
<m:SplitButton Content="TWB" Name="btnSearch"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource aeroNormalColorSplitButtonStyle}"
                    Click="btnSearch_Click" 
                    Width="60" Height="30"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                    Mode="{Binding ElementName=modeSelector, Path=SelectedItem}"
                    Placement="{Binding ElementName=placementSelector, Path=SelectedItem}">
                    <ListBox x:Name="TransitionKind" SelectionChanged="TransitionKind_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBoxItem Content="TWB"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="PWB"/>
                    </ListBox>
                </m:SplitButton>
```

in the code behind,

btnSearch.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnSearch_Click);
                  TransitionKind.SelectionChanged   += new System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(TransitionKind_SelectionChanged);

private void TransitionKind_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                  btnSearch.Content = ((ListBoxItem)TransitionKind.SelectedItem).Content;
                  txtBxSearch.Text = "Search " + (string) btnSearch.Content;
            }

Now, I am able to see the text in the textbox changing to the click of dropdown button.

Thank you,
Ramm